# Button calling a function in Maya

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I'm trying to make a button in a function that calls another function inside a class.

That's what I did:

```
# button calling functions
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel
from functools import partial

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_window()

    def printText(self, text, *args):
        print(text)
        return

    def create_window(self):
        window = cmds.window()
        cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2, columnWidth=[(1, 50), (1, 70)])
        cmds.text(label='Name')
        axis = cmds.textField()
        cmds.showWindow(window)
        text_entered = cmds.textField(axis, query=True, text=True)
        #cmd = 'printText("{0}")'.format(text_entered)
        cmds.button(label="asd", command = partial(self.printText, text_entered))
        return       

a = B()
```

The problem is I get printed nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not getting the contents of `text_entered`, you're printing an object

Comment: it returns a string notice the flags

Answer (score 1):

founded a solution but i thing it's a bit strange

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_window()

    def create_window(self):
        if cmds.window("UI", exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI("UI")
        win = cmds.window("UI")
        cmds.columnLayout()
        textEntered = cmds.textField()

        def print_text_contents(a):
            print cmds.textField(textEntered, query=True, text=True)

        cmds.button(label='Confirm', command=print_text_contents)
        cmds.showWindow(win)


B()
```

Comment: You created a new TextField from a TextField? How does that work? What was the error in my answer?

Comment: I'm not creating a textField from a textField.
I'm getting the text of a particular textField, look the documentation:
http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/show.html?textField.html&cat=Windows

Comment: Depending on the flags you use, cmds.textfield can return a string of the text entered in a specified textField, in my case textEntered, that is an object. Note the "query" flag is set to True.
I hope i explained it better

Comment: this is legit (although by convention you want to use "_" for the ignored argument in `print_text_contents`.  Reasons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/maya/7627/creating-maya-ui/25096/callback-functions#t=20170801170501701825)

Comment: @cricket_007 its in what theodox said, the error of your code is that:
# Error: printText() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: @cricket_007 i dont understand exactly why. But when i put the function printText in the createWindow function it works fine

Comment: @akerbeltz Oh, okay, so my answer would work if I added `printText(self, _ignored)`

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, but it prints nothing

Comment: Well, `self.text_entered` could be an empty string

Comment: @cricket_007 I think as written you're capturing the value of the text field's content on creation (so it's an empty string)  and then reporting the captured value.  If you wanted to re-query you'd want a lambda or a closure, which is why OP's revised version works

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need a partial function when you can let the text field be a member variable of the class

```
def printText(self, _ignored):
    print(">>" + self.text_entered)  # note this is an object, not the contents 
    return

def create_window(self):
    window = cmds.window()
    cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2, columnWidth=[(1, 50), (1, 70)])
    cmds.text(label='Name')
    axis = cmds.textField()
    cmds.showWindow(window)
    self.text_entered = cmds.textField(axis, query=True, text=True)
    #cmd = 'printText("{0}")'.format(text_entered)
    cmds.button(label="asd", command =self.printText)
    return
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but your code gives an error in maya. You can't call a function in the command parameter.
Anyways i really want to know how to do that with partial function.

Comment: I'm not calling a function, I am passing a handle to one, which is what the partial function would do.